# Flag para arrancar chrome con un zoom predeterminado

Tags: google-chrome

Para unas pruebas en UFT necesito arrancar el explorador chrome maximizado pero con un zoom determinado. Para arrancarlo maximizado he visto que hay que añadir el flag `-start-maximized`, pero no he encontrado un flag para que arranque con el zoom de 70 %.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 3" -start-maximized
```

Answer (score 2):

No se si hay manera más fácil pero lo que se me ocurre es que instales en chrome la extension [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=es) y crees un script personalizado que sea asi:

---

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Zoom predeterminado

// @description Pone un zoom personalizado a las paginas del include
// @include     https://www.google.es/*
// @include     http://es.stackoverflow.com/*

// @version     1.1
// @grant       
// ==/UserScript==

document.body.style.zoom = "70%";
```

---

Puedes poner tantas lineas de `@include` como quieras para especificar las paginas donde va a actuar. Si quieres que actue en todas pon `@include *://*/*`

Y abajo pon el `%` de zoom que necesites.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo configuras en el navegador haciendo click en "Personaliza y controla Google Chrome" --> Configuración, luego hacer click en "Mostrar configuración avanzada…" y busca la parte que dice "Contenido Web", allí se puede cambiar el zoom.

Answer (score 0):

si añades el parametro `--force-device-scale-factor=1.5` aparece escalado a 1.5
Aquí tienes un listado con todos los parámetros que le puedes mandar:
https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/